# How do I use those digital LEDs with an I2C device?

Tags: microcontroller, led, digital-logic, i2c

I want to use the MMA8453Q accelerometer via I2C while at the same time sending data to some WS2812B-2020 digital LEDs. I am thinking of using the PIC16F1789 microcontroller.

Since I can't hook the LEDs up to the I2C bus as well, I first wanted to just send data via a normal digital I/O. I need to be able to send 43200 bits per second to the LEDs but I can't find out how high the maximum frequency of a normal I/O of the microcontroller is. I also don't know if this is the smartest way to do this or if there is an easier way.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing; the WS2812 has this weird daisy-chainable PWM control, and you'll more or less need to bit-bang it, anyway. So the question you're asking is "can I write software that's fast enough at bit-banging AND handling I²C", and we can't tell you; we don't know what that software needs to do with the data it gets or how it computes the things it sends, how often you'll do I²C transfers, and how good you are at programming.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't know if it helps, but the microcontroller can do up to 32MHz. I'll execute about 20 - 30 I2C transfers (reads) a second. And are you saying that I could generate a PWM signal with a timer and use that to send data to the LED's without having to bit-bang?

Comment: no, I specifically said you need to bit-bang.

Comment: The WS2812 bit stream refresh must be uninterrupted (bit-bang timing has little margin on a typical controller), so you need to determine if your I2C accesses can be interrupted for this period.  If your I2C accesses are not required to be spaced out equally over 1 second, you should not have a problem. If the I2C accesses must be spaced out equally, the answer will depend on how many LEDs are in the chain. You could also consider creating multiple LED chains.

Comment: Does the PIC have a WS2812 library? If not, it might be easier all round to switch to a micro that *does* have a WS2812 library.

Comment: The PIC can output bits as fast as your code can.

Answer (score 0):

Each device on the I2C bus has its own address. As long as you don't have  a conflict, you can use both of them. If they do have the same address, the accelerometer has the SA0 line to change the LSB of the address from 0 to 1.